# Displaying same products with different images... PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a website for people to post their cars for sale. I've done posting data into database. Everything works fine, but when they go to Member's page, it should show them added cars with photo, and edit button.

Here's my function to display added cars:

```
function get_user_auto($username) {
//extract from the database all the URLs this user has stored
$conn = db_connect();
$result = $conn->query("
SELECT 
images.filename,
car_make.make, 
car_model.model, 
car_generation.name,
cars.year,
cars.price,
cars.car_id
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN car_make ON cars.make = car_make.make_id 
LEFT JOIN car_model ON cars.model = car_model.model_id 
LEFT JOIN car_generation ON cars.generation = car_generation.generation_id 
LEFT JOIN images ON cars.car_id = images.car_id 
WHERE cars.username = '$username';");

if (!$result) {
return false;         
}
//create an array of the URLs
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $make = $row["make"];
    $model = $row["model"];
    $generation = $row["name"];
    $year = $row["year"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $filename = $row["filename"];
    $imageURL = 'uploads/'.$filename;

        ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" width="100"/>
            </div>
            <div>
            <?php echo "" . $make ." " . $model ." - " . $year ." " . $price ." USD";?>

            <a href="edit_car_form.php">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php

}
} else {
echo "You did not add car for sale yet.";
}
}
```

So, i.e. I have added one car with 3 photos attached to it by car_id, when I retrieve data and echo it, it shows the same car 3 times with 3 different photos.

Comment: It seems it's SQL query problem, not PHP. What does query return?

Comment: @Volvox Well, it returns 3 times  3 different image filenames, but same car make, model, year, price and id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only one row per car then you can add `GROUP BY` to query like this
`GROUP BY car_id`. This will allow only one row per car_id regardless of how many images car have (but it might not select image you like).